# What does "drag-data-delete" signal do?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3

I learned too many drag and drop signals. but this `self.btn1.connect("drag-data-delete", self.do_anything)` code line not working. when drag-drop process started and finished, `do_anything` function not working.

How can I ensure work this codeline?

Comment: what was the behaviour you experienced? Was there some error/exception anywhere?

Comment: @BojanPetkovic, no nothing happened (no error, no ...) program continued to work correctly

Comment: @BojanPetkovic, can you give me example code ? if you know how does work.

Comment: not my domain, sorry.  I just moderated the question, it was not very clear to me at the start.

Comment: @BojanPetkovic, okey thanks.

Comment: @Nomad, since you are using a Gtk.Button (assumed from btn1) then this signal is inherited from Gtk.Widget. The [API says](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-drag-data-delete): "The ::drag-data-delete signal is emitted on the drag source when a drag with the action GDK_ACTION_MOVE is successfully completed. The signal handler is responsible for deleting the data that has been dropped. What "delete" means depends on the context of the drag operation."  So in your context, if you don't need to do any cleaning of resources etc so this signal, maybe, is not necessary.

Comment: I also suspect - though didn't try - that 'data-delete' doesn't make sense if the drag operation is set to mode 'COPY'. In that case it doesn't make sense to delete data at the source.

Comment: isn't  there a any expert pygtk user to solve this question in stackoverflow ?

Comment: The comments from José Fonte and jcoppens seemed plausible enough. Did you try and verify those?